# How to run start /wait and then execute another command on one line as one command?

Tags: command-prompt, windows-installer, errorlevel

I am trying to use the following command in a command prompt:

```
    start /wait msiexec /i WebPlatformInstaller_3_10_amd64_en-US.msi /qn /l*v c:\webplatform.log & echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

The issue I am having is that the command is returning the %ERRORLEVEL% before the msiexec process has finished.

When I run the two commands separately (in a command prompt or batch script) i.e. run the following then it does return the %ERRORLEVEL% correctly (after the process has finished):

```
    start /wait msiexec /i WebPlatformInstaller_3_10_amd64_en-US.msi /qn /l*v c:\webplatform.log
    echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

However I would like to run these commands on one line as one command and not two separate ones, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

First, adding "& echo %ERRORLEVEL%" to your first line should do what you want. The ampersand character is the standard character for queuing two commands on one line (if you have not changed the default on your system).

I cannot exactly reproduce your problem. "start /wait msiexec /i .." waits fine on my system.
But in a case on an ERROR I also have seen another ERRORLEVEL value in one line than on two, so things are a bit weird here.
I have seen strange things with start.exe and don't like it much
But why you are so eager to call everything from the command line ?
Doing it from a batch file (with "call msiexec...") is more safe in my experience.

But one more tip either:

Try using /qb instead of /qn. This resulted in the same ERRORLEVEL in my case. Seems that it only waits fully with a dialog box or so actve maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is indistinct.

DO you mean that the line shows the value even though the `start`ed command has not yet completed?

Or do you mean that the value shown is the value of `errorlevel` prior to the `start` command, not the value established by the `start` command (although the response is obtained *after* the `start`ed command has completed?

I'd try

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
start .....&echo !errorlevel!
```

It'll still be 2 lines though, unless you use the `setlocal` as the line following `@echo off` (in the customary manner)